# Missing "Value" field in Visualization pane of Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am now only seeing the "Y-asix", "X-asix", "Legend' options in the Visualization pane. I cannot see "Values" option any more in the Visualization pane , sorry that i can't pasty image to this questions

Answer (score 0):

The fields you see depend on the visual selected, e.g.

- Clustered column charts or Line charts don't have a VALUES field
- Pie chart and Matrix do have a VALUES field

[image]